# call back in dbms_scheduler job Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

When we start a job via dbms_schedular, it creates a record in *_SCHEDULER_JOBS
Is there a way at the middle or end of a job. I write onto the record

Example:
Job_A spawns Procedure_B
And inside Procedure_B, I can write back to the record in *_scheduler_jobs in Job_A

As procedure_B is looping on a sequence of sub-task e.g. batch_id=1 to 10
and I want to write id=1 and id=10 into the entry for Job_A in *_SCHEDULER_JOBS

-Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague on "I want to write id=1 and id=10 into the entry for Job_A in *_SCHEDULER_JOBS".

From within the procedure, you can use the SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID') to get the object id of the scheduler job, and look the owner / name up in ALL_OBJECTS. If the job is owned by the same user as the procedure or has been granted appropriate privileges, it can then call DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE to make changes to the job. Depending what attribute it changes, that will probably only kick in for the next run of the job.

BG_JOB_ID only works if the job is run from the scheduler, and not if someone is doing dbms_scheduler.run_job within their own session. Given multiple sessions could do this concurrently, you probably don't want them all trying to make changes to the job anyway.